# Declare local variable: how convert this mssql script to oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dbmigrate

```
declare @amount float
declare @result char (20)

select @amount = cost from PurchaseDoc where id = 1

if @amount > 0 set @result = 'ok'
else set @result = 'empty'

print @result
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one representation of your script which can be executed against an Oracle database:

```
DECLARE
    amount    NUMBER;
    result    varchar2(20);
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(cost) INTO amount
      from PurchaseDoc
     WHERE id = 1;

    if (amount > 0) 
    then
        result := 'ok';
    else 
        result := 'empty';      
    end if;

    dbms_output.put_line(result);    
END;
/
```

See this [link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:45027262935845) for some useful information about dbms_output.
I recommend taking a look at some PL/SQL tutorials, such as the ones located at [www.plsql-tutorial.com](http://www.plsql-tutorial.com/).

**EDIT** 
Updated select statement based on suggestion by Cade Roux

Comment: I would change that to SUM(cost) for simplicity, because if no rows exist, you with get a NO_DATA_FOUND exception which will need to be handled in the transition from SQL to PL/SQL (SELECT is SQL, INTO variable is PL/SQL).  You don't have this issue in T-SQL, where they are more tightly integrated.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need for PL/SQL here, a normal select statement with 'decode' function can do the trick.

```sql
SELECT DECODE(SUM(COST),0,'empty','ok') FROM PurchaseDoc where id = 1;
```